# css style tag is not evaluated in safari

Tags: css, safari

I want to load background images by css dependent on the display resolution with the @media keyword. It works fine in Firefox and chrome, but it does not work in Safari. Is there something I miss?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>

        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>Snowboardschule: Skigebiet</title>

        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/fileadmin/css/style.css?1496823820" media="all" title="main">

        <style type="text/css">@media(min-resolution: 1dppx){ .trailer { background-image: url(fileadmin/_processed_/e/d/csm_trailer1_ca6cb9b743.jpg); }}</style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <header>
            <div class="trailer">
                ...  
            </div>
        </header>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Safari will filter only with retina displays. Try change the min-resolution values to observe the changes. Check also for console errors.

Comment: I added another min-resolution, but nothing changed. And I got no console errors. I tried it on iPad Air, iPhone6s and a Macbook Pro. No result

Answer (score 0):

Try using

```
<style type="text/css">
@media and screen (min-resolution: 1dppx)
  { .trailer { background-image: url(fileadmin/_processed_/e/d/csm_trailer1_ca6cb9b743.jpg); }}
</style>
```

Comment: Another way around this is to use JavaScript or jQuery to say when its ios display that image and use px media querie in the function i done it once works great. If you cant find it let me know and i can give you the coding to do it that way.